# Can you pass ruby objects to haml during a render?

Tags: ruby, haml

I'm trying to create a haml template that uses some data from my ruby app to fill in some content.  Is it possible to pass arguments into haml to make it render correctly?  Here's how I'm getting my haml template and rendering it:

```
template = File.open('path/to/template.haml')
html = Haml::Engine.new(template.read).render
```

So, is it possible to pass objects from the local Ruby script into the template file so that they the page is rendered correctly?  Or, can I have the haml file pull in objects?

If this doesn't work, my only other idea is building up the template as a local string which seems more tedious to me.  So, is there a different coding pattern that is more efficient for this job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes,

Check the docs:
http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Engine.html#render-instance_method

- (String) render(scope = Object.new, locals = {}, &block)

pass them as locals

Comment: As I understand it, "locals" must be a hash... and I'm about to embark on getting a json tree of objects into that render method
Admittedly, I haven't just tried it yet, but is this a limitation then?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do it using ruby:

```
template = File.read('path/to/template.haml')
html = Haml::Engine.new(template).render(Object.new, :my_object => my_object)
```